# Mindstorms crashes when connecting to EV3 with Bluetooth

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, software

I am using OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) on a 2011 MacBook Air, LEGO Mindstorms EV3 Home Edition v1.0 and the latest firmware on the EV3 (v1.06H)

When I attempt to pair the EV3 with my Mac over Bluetooth, then Mindstorms consistently crashes.

Here's what I do:

1. Connect the EV3 with the USB cable
2. Select "Refresh" in Mindstorms
3. OS X prompts me to pair the EV3
4. I click "Pair"
5. Beachball appears for a couple of seconds, and Mindstorms crashes.

Any hints on what to do?

Comment: There appears to be a [known issue](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/4598/56) with the Bluetooth stack in Yosemite. Until this is resolved, you won't be able to pair the EV3 with a Mac.

Comment: It works now, with the latest version (1.1.1) of Mindstorms.

Comment: Sweet, glad it's sorted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help to the problems:
If you download the latest version of mindstorms by the Mindstorms-Site you´ll get the version 1.1.1.then you can connect via Bluetooth to the brick with the newest version EV3 (v1.o6H)
But if you are like me a teacher and using the educational version of Mindstorms (version 1.1.0 (note the last zero)), then you will have serious problems to connect your brick using Bluetooth in OS Yosemite!

Answer (score 1):

Try pairing it while the LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 software is closed using Bluetooth in System Settings. Then open the LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 software and try to connect.

Comment: Sorry, but Pairing the EV3-Brick isn´t possible, because it isn´t listed in the Bluetooth-objects.

Answer (score 1):

Pairing it while the LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 software is closed is the way to do it. Using Bluetooth in System Settings to connect the laptop to the robot first, then open the LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 software and establish the connection with the robot.

You need to update education software to 1.1.1.

Get the patch from:

https://education.lego.com/en-us/educationdownloads/download?assetid=14d8bec7-9de6-4d9b-ab8f-891993ecf501&ignorereferer=true