# Is the LEGO Midstorms EV3 software compatible with OS X Yosemite?

Tags: ev3, compatibility

OS X Yosemite (10.10) was just released yesterday. I want to upgrade, but I am worried that the EV3 software will be incompatible.

What should I do?

A. Upgrade

B. Stay on OS X Mavericks (10.9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The educational software of mindstorms is not yet updated.(Version 1.1.0)
If you download the free version of mindstorms (Version 1.1.1) you can connect via Bluetooth under Yosemite to your brick!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to resort to the cable because the bluetooth wasn't working. I'm so happy the the update fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

B. Stay with OS X Mavericks.  I can confirm that bluetooth no longer works with Yosemite. Spent two hours trying to make it work, but in vain.

Comment: The new update v1.1.1 for the programming software fixes the issue. See below.

Answer (score 1):

I have run the LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 software successfully on Yosemite Beta for a couple weeks. The only problem I have had is that I cannot get Bluetooth to work. The bluetooth problem appears to be at the OS level rather than a software compatibility issue though.

Update:

I reported this to Apple via https://bugreport.apple.com. It was marked as a duplicate, so apparently Apple knows about it. Unfortunately, their bug reporting system is not very open and you can only see your own bugs. There is no other feed back on the status of getting it resolved.
I would suggest that everyone that has the problem report the bug as well. This should let Apple know there is demand to get this fixed and hopefully they will make it a priority.

Comment: Same here. Upgraded my MBAir (late 2013) to Yosemite and now can't connect over bluetooth to the brick (EV3) anymore...

Comment: Same, my EV3 bluetooth no longer works with Yosemite :-(